# IOS connect to Firebird

Tags: ios, database-connection, firebird

i want my application to connect with a Firebird Database.

Exists something like the SQLClient library of Martin Rybak?
(http://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/an-open-source-sql-server-library-for-ios/)

I've found libraries for MySQL and PostgreSQL and the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is one and you can try it feedback would be appreciated.

http://paulbeachsblog.blogspot.ro/2013/09/an-update-about-firebird-on-ios.html

Comment: I can't extract the .tar - file.
MacOSX says "Error 1 - process unadmitted"

Comment: I have tested on Ubuntu and i could extract the tar file , please try to extract from command line tar -xvf ~/Downloads/FirebirdIOSembed.tar